# Windows hangs on spinning dots

Tags: boot, windows-10, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I did the most stupid move ever. I downloaded an Intel auto-detect-and-update tool from their website and ever since whenever I start windows with my 960GTX, It hangs on the spinning dots.

I swapped the card with my old ATI 6770HD and everything worked fine so I thought something was wrong with the card. Tried the card on my brother's PC - no problem.

So I figured it has something to do with windows. Reinstalled windows still the same. So I figured maybe faulty BIOS update. Downloaded the latest for my MOBO, flashed properly and still the same.

Important notes:

- The system used to work before I installed the "utility".
- The GPU is brand new (+- 3 months old)
- Voltage readings seemed ok using a software I can't recall.
- I tried DDU from guru3d but it didn't work.
- Safe mode NOT possible with 960GTX

What could be the cause of this? I'm literally flipping out.

Specs:

- CPU: i7 860 (first gen)
- MOBO: GA-P55A-UD3
- GPU (faulty?): EVGA Nvidia GTX960 4Gb
- PSU: Corsair 650W

Comment: The Intel auto detect itself doesn't really do a lot, it'll query your drivers and check for updates. It certainly shouldn't do anything to cause harm after a reinstall of Windows. Perhaps more likely is some recent Nvidia update causing an issue, perhaps try and older driver and not using the Geforce Experience application to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: I can't even boot to safe mode with my 960GTX man. did you read my post at all?

Comment: I read your post. I read it again. I've just read it a third time. Nowhere do you say that there is no way for you to access safe mode. You say it hangs on spinning circles and works fine with another card, thus I assume you have a way you can access and uninstall an old driver. If you feel my comment was misguided, I can only go on what you're written. Perhaps you could amend the guidance to make things clearer?

Comment: Sorry I'm just frustrated that's all. I can't boot to safe mode with the card plugged in. Whenever I get to the spinning dots they suddenly freeze and the GPU's fans are not spinning.

Comment: Thing is I can change bios settings with the 960. It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Took the PC to a hardware dude. no apparent damage to components. all he did was change the SATA port from marvell to Intel's and it loads just fine.